# SUM and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sum

I have this table

```
Pupil ID    Fname   Lname   Form    House   Week Nr     Data
104     fname1  lname1  Year 5W Junior  Frobisher   3   5
106     fname2  lname2  Year 4W Junior  Grenville   2   5
106     fname2  lname2  Year 4W Junior  Grenville   3   4
106     fname2  lname2  Year 4W Junior  Grenville   4   3
106     fname2  lname2  Year 4W Junior  Grenville   5   5
107     fname3  lname3  Year 5W Junior  Grenville   1   1
107     fname3  lname3  Year 5W Junior  Grenville   2   3
107     fname3  lname3  Year 5W Junior  Grenville   3   5
107     fname3  lname3  Year 5W Junior  Grenville   4   1

SELECT PPD.PupilID, PPD.Forename, PPD.Surname, FL.[Description] AS 'Form', HL.[Description] AS 'House', CAST(REPLACE(CM.ColumnTitle, 'Week ', '') AS INT) AS 'WeekNo',CAST(MSDN.Data AS INT) AS 'Data', SUM(CAST(MSDN.Data AS INT)) AS 'Total'
FROM CurrentPupil 
INNER JOIN PupilPersonalDetails AS PPD ON PPD.PupilID = CurrentPupil.PupilID   
INNER JOIN PupilCurrentSchool AS PCS ON PCS.PupilID = PPD.PupilID 
INNER JOIN SchoolLookupDetails AS FL ON PCS.Form = FL.LookupDetailsID AND FL.LookupID = 1002 
INNER JOIN SchoolLookupDetails AS HL ON PCS.House = HL.LookupDetailsID AND HL.LookupID = 1001 
INNER JOIN MarksheetDataNumeric AS MSDN ON MSDN.PupilID = PPD.PupilID 
INNER JOIN ColumnsMaster AS CM ON CM.ColumnID = MSDN.ColumnID AND CM.ColumnTitle LIKE '%week%' 
INNER JOIN ClusterMaster AS CLM ON CLM.ClusterID = SUBSTRING(PPD.SchoolID, 0, 4) 
INNER JOIN ColumnReportingPeriods AS CRP ON CRP.ColumnID = CM.ColumnID 
INNER JOIN ReportingPeriods AS RP ON RP.AcademicYear = CLM.CurrentAcademicYear AND RP.ReportingPeriodID = CRP.ReportingPeriodID
WHERE ('%wc%' = '%wc%')
GROUP BY PPD.PupilID
```

I am trying to SUM the following column
CAST(MSDN.Data AS INT) AS 'Data'

and add a new one as a total points for each ID (pupil)
CAST(MSDN.Data AS INT) AS 'Data', SUM(CAST(MSDN.Data AS INT)) AS 'Total',
(I think it is right!)
but the outcome is:
Column PupilPersonalDetails.ForeName is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You don't have to cast MSDN.Data to INT, but you can't have MSDN.Data and SUM(MSDN.Data) in one select according to your case.

Comment: In most databases the fields you use in the select also need to be in the GROUP BY. Except those in an aggregate function like MAX, SUM, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from this:

```
SELECT PPD.PupilID
,PPD.Forename
,PPD.Surname
,SUM(MSDN.Data) 'Total'
FROM CurrentPupil 
INNER JOIN PupilPersonalDetails PPD ON PPD.PupilID=CurrentPupil.PupilID   
INNER JOIN PupilCurrentSchool PCS ON PCS.PupilID=PPD.PupilID 
INNER JOIN SchoolLookupDetails FL ON PCS.Form=FL.LookupDetailsID AND FL.LookupID=1002 
INNER JOIN SchoolLookupDetails HL ON PCS.House=HL.LookupDetailsID AND HL.LookupID=1001 
INNER JOIN MarksheetDataNumeric MSDN ON MSDN.PupilID=PPD.PupilID 
INNER JOIN ColumnsMaster CM ON CM.ColumnID=MSDN.ColumnID AND CM.ColumnTitle LIKE '%week%' 
INNER JOIN ClusterMaster CLM ON CLM.ClusterID=SUBSTRING(PPD.SchoolID,0,4) 
INNER JOIN ColumnReportingPeriods CRP ON CRP.ColumnID=CM.ColumnID
INNER JOIN ReportingPeriods RP ON RP.AcademicYear=CLM.CurrentAcademicYear AND RP.ReportingPeriodID=CRP.ReportingPeriodID
WHERE ('%wc%'='%wc%')
GROUP BY PPD.PupilID
,PPD.Forename
,PPD.Surname
```

If you want to have more columns in the result you can add them, but since you are using an aggregation function SUM you have to have all these columns - except the one you are aggregating (summing in this case) - mentioned in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked a treat. 
if i want to retreive just the records with 17 points.. is this right?
WHERE ('%wc%' = '%wc%') AND Total=17

Comment: No. You have to add HAVING clause when you want to filter the aggregates. So: .... WHERE ('%wc%' = '%wc%') GROUP BY PPD.PupilID
,PPD.Forename
,PPD.Surname HAVING SUM(MSDN.Data)=17 . If I helped please rate my answer.

Comment: And one more thing: ('%wc%' = '%wc%') is useless in this case. It means the same as 1=1 - it is always true. Since WHERE is a filter on rows - not aggregates - in your case it doesn't remove any rows, because it always evaluates to true. You can remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: Use the arrows on the left of the answer above.

Comment: You can get rid of "INNER". "INNER JOIN"=''JOIN". "JOIN" is implicit "INNER JOIN" - don't mix it with "RIGHT JOIN" OR "LEFT JOIN" etc.